# error to start the apache on my xampp

Tags: apache, xampp

When I try to start the apache, it will automatically close.
so i couldn't run any application on my browser.
what should i do?
and the error appear should this:

```
11:20:19 AM  [Apache]   Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
11:20:19 AM  [Apache]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
11:20:19 AM  [Apache]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
11:20:19 AM  [Apache]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
11:20:19 AM  [Apache]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
11:20:19 AM  [Apache]   If you need more help, copy and post this
11:20:19 AM  [Apache]   entire log window on the forums
```

Comment: Have you checked the error logs?

Comment: where i check my error logs?

Comment: i didnt see any error that appear on my error log.